# how to compare/match/replace javascript (regex) string with another string ignoring string order

Tags: javascript, regex

say i had a string `var str = "this is the string";`

i want to compare it against this string `var str2 = "string is the";`

and i want this to return true or matched string with javascript and regex

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: i had tried alot.

Comment: i tried str.match function and str.test function str.reverse function but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation I have created an example of what you require. In this example of code I have created a function that will accept two strings, they will be split by any non-word character and then compared regardless of the word order in the string. If strings are the same, that is contain the same words disregarding the word order, it will return true.

```js
let string1 = "this is the string";
let string2 = "string is the this";

function findMatch( string1, string2 ) {
 //split by any non-word character, anything that is not
        //a-z, A-Z, 0-9 ( including the _ character )
 let splitPattern = /\W/;
 let split1 = string1.split( splitPattern );
        let split2 = string2.split( splitPattern );
 
    //traverse string1 array 
 for ( let i = 0; i < split1.length; i++ ) {
           let checkForMatch = false;
          //traverse string2 array
     for( let j = 0; j < split2.length; j++ ) {
         if ( split1[ i ] === split2[ j ] ) {
              checkForMatch = true;
              break;
            }
          }//inner for
    
    //if match not found in one itteration, strings do not
    //match and false should be returned
    if ( !checkForMatch ) {
     return false;
    }
  }//outer for
  
  //else it matches so return true
   return true;
 
}//end findMatch

console.log( findMatch( string1, string2 ) );
```

I hope this is of help to you.

EDIT: Otherwise if you simply want to check if string2 exists within string1, you can switch the two arrays with split results in the for loops.